# Вся ли бизнес-логика приложения не должна содержаться в контроллерах?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

*Вопрос по платформе ASP.NET Core с применением паттерна MVC.*

В интернете везде пишут бизнес-логику веб-приложений в контроллерах, а в моделях содержат лишь описания предметной области т.е. классы, поля и свойства. А также объекты, которые будут храниться в БД.
Я сам разработчик на C# из тех, кто привык к WPF или WinForms.

---

Придя на собеседование в Сбербанк на вакансию ASP.NET Core MVC разработчиком, я начал рассказывать о том, что в моделях правильнее содержать описания предметной области т.е. классы, поля и свойства. А также объекты, которые будут храниться в БД. Поскольку начитался этой информации и усвоил ее (других более правильных версий не находил). А вся реализация и бизнес-логика должна содержаться в контроллерах.
На что мне ответили с уверенностью, что я совсем не верно понимаю архитектуру MVC, и после моей просьбы объяснить мне подробнее, мне ответили вот такую версию назвав ее более правильной относительно архитектуры построения приложений на MVC.

1. Модели должны быть максимально толстыми (т.е. в них вся бизнес-логика и вообще любая логика приложений).
2. Контроллеры должны быть максимально тонкими (т.е. в них не должно быть никакой бизнес-логики и реализаций методов кроме запросов POST, GET).
3. Представления вообще не должны содержать никогда никакой бизнес-логики, а лишь отображать данные моделей, которые передают свои данные через контроллер.

В архитектуре MVC, какая из этих двух версий более правильная?

Comment: Спор anemic vs rich domain model длится уже много лет и на него нет однозначного ответа. В одних компаниях предпочитают первый подход, в других - второй. Освойте оба и будьте готовы гибко подстраиваться под нужды заказчика. Если спросят, что будете использовать, отвечайте: тот вариант, который принят в вашей фирме.